# c# split arithmetic expression to string[]

Tags: c#, regex, regular-language

I have a simple arithmetic expression containing integers, parentheses, and **+-*/**. Like this:

`((1+33)()(4+(3-5)))`

What I need to do is split this expression to the `string[]` like this:

`{(, (, 1, +, 33, ), (, ), (, 4, +, (, 3, -, 5, ), ), )}`

I am trying to do it with `Regex` class

```
public string[] SplitString(string str)
{
     return Regex.Split(str, "(?<=[()-+*/])|(?=[()-+*/])");
}
```

But output data is not quite right:

`{(, (, 1, +, 33, ), (, ), (, 4, +, (, **3-5**, ), ), )}`

Comment: You can compute the result without splitting it. Is this what you are after ?

Comment: Note that `)-+` create a range in your char class that matches more than you might expect. Put the hyphen at the end of the character class.

Comment: Beside that unescaped dash, I suggest to consider to do the other way: match the desired tokens and return a list of all matches - you'll end up with a simpler regex: `return Regex.Matches(str, @"([()+*/-]|\d+)").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match a dash, it needs to be in the first or the last position in a character class in regex:

```
(?<=[()+*/-])|(?=[()+*/-])
//        ^            ^
```

Otherwise, it is interpreted as a character range - in your case, from `)` to `*`.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/cF7Mn7)

Answer (score 1):

If it's just the 3-5 causing you problems, you need to escape the "-" in your pattern i.e.

```
Regex.Split(str, "(?<=[()\\-+*/])|(?=[()\\-+*/])")
```